# How to convert Unix file Path to Windows Path using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, path

I'm using acrobat that returns unix paths instead of windows path's. So im wondering if there is a way in vb.net to convert the path to windows path.

i tried using:

```
docs(i) = javaScriptObj.path().ToString.Replace("/", "\").Substring(1)
position = docs(i).IndexOf("\")
docs(i) = docs(i).Substring(0, position) + ":\" + docs(i).Substring(position + 1)
```

this only works on local files, but fails when im starting to use network drives. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Private Function UnixPathToWindowsPath(UnixPath As String) As String
   If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UnixPath) Then Return String.Empty
   Dim chunks = UnixPath.Split(New Char() {"/"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   If chunks.Any Then
      If chunks(0).Length = 1 Then 'Single character root, assume drive letter.
         Return String.Join("\", chunks).Insert(1, ":")
      Else
         Return "\\" & String.Join("\", chunks)
      End If
   Else
      Return IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
   End If
End Function
```

This assumes full path names, and not partial paths.